# how to append a dataframe to existing csv file and remove the duplicates data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, duplicates

i have a dataframe data and csv data as following
[image]

[image]

i want to append the dataframe data to the csv file.however ,there are duplicates  between the two data.so how to remove the duplicates and append new data to csv file.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
pd.read_csv('file').append(df).drop_duplicates().to_csv('file')
```

Comment: `to_csv` instead of `to_file` :)